# add image to PHP email script

Tags: php, forms, email

I've done some research on this issue but still can't find an answer that I understand. Basically I'm trying to add a Logo to the emails sent via my email PHP script. The code of my PHP script is:

```
<?php
$name = $_POST['Name'];
$email = $_POST['Email'];
$sub = $_POST['Subject'];
$message = $_POST['Message'];


$Subject = "$sub";
$Sendto = "Omitted for privacy reasons";


mail($Sendto,$Subject,
"$message

Email: $email
Name: $name
"
,"From: $email,$name");
?>
```

How do I go about putting an image held on my server in Images/logo above the email:$email part of the message?

thanks

As a side question can anyone provide me with a guide or reading on how to beautify the message as its so plain

Comment: specify text/html in your mail headers and then write your email markup as you would any old style html4 markup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you might do is to send the mail not as "text/plain", but as "text/html".
You e-mail content is then basically a static webpage and you can insert images to.

**Example Code for Mail with HTML Content**

```
$to = 'to@someone.com';
$subject = 'The Subject';

$headers = "From: " . strip_tags($_POST['req-email']) . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: ". strip_tags($_POST['req-email']) . "\r\n";
$headers .= "CC: other@someone.com\r\n";
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
// this is the important header to set the type
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";

// now $message can be a static html page like:
$message = '<html><body>';
$message .= '<h1>Hello, World!</h1>';
$message .= '</body></html>';

// with image embedded
$message = '<html><body>';
$message .= '<h1>Hello, World!</h1>';
$message .= '<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qmw3Z.jpg?s=32&g=1" alt="AVTR" />';
$message .= '</body></html>';
```

**Important:** If you insert something into the message coming from POST, do not forget to escape it properly with `htmlentities($_POST['somevar'])` or `striptags`.

Then send mail:
    `mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);`

Answer to side-quest: "can anyone provide me with a guide or reading on how to beautify the message as its so plain". When you send the mail as HTML you might apply CSS styles to your HTML.

- Starter tutorial: http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/articles/build-an-html-email-template-from-scratch--webdesign-12770
- you might also google for "html email templates", download one and modify to your needs

Comment: Many thanks for your help but could you elaborate on the escape/striptags thing? Sorry I'm really new to PHP

Comment: No problem. Two things are essential: input filtering and output escaping. Input filtering and validation makes sure, that only values get into your system, which you want. Lets take $_GET['name'] incomming from a form field "name". The user enters "7777". That might be a valid nickname, but not a proper name. You have to define, what a proper name is for your system, like "name" should be "only chars azAz0-9". Topic is "form validation on server side".

Comment: Output escaping makes sure, that no unwanted content is send to the output. If you don't properly escape output for email headers or message content, a moderately clever attacker can hijack the entire message and replace it with one of their own, sent to whoever they like with whatever content they like. More info: https://www.inanimatt.com/php-output-escaping.html

Comment: After doing some more research twinned with this answer, I have managed to completely reformat my message and they now look wonderful, thank you so much